# Python - removing unnecessary parenthesise from expression

Tags: python, formatting, expression, brackets, parentheses

I have an expression such as this :

`((6)) - (5 * ((((1))) + 1) * 6) - 4`

and

`((((((3))) - 5 * (((2))) * ((5)))))`

Is there a pythonic way in which I can remove some of the unnecessary bracketing so that the expressions would look like:

```
6-(5 *(1+1) *6) -4 and 
3-5 * (2*5)
```

I am new to python and am unsure at all how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Get a parser generator, write a parser, parse the expression, and then unparse the parse tree.

Comment: I would guess `ast.parse()` should help.

Comment: You could eliminate not only the excess parentheses but also some of the numbers and all the operators with `eval`, which would produce `-58` and `-47` for those lines.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 With all my respect, this is clearly not what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the expression with `ast.parse` and then convert it back to a simplified string using `ast.unparse`. This works as long as the expression you are trying to simplify constitutes valid Python code.

```
>>> ast.unparse(ast.parse("((6)) - (5 * ((((1))) + 1) * 6) - 4"))
'6 - 5 * (1 + 1) * 6 - 4'
>>> ast.unparse(ast.parse("((((((3))) - 5 * (((2))) * ((5)))))"))
'3 - 5 * 2 * 5'
```